# Sourcing bash scripts in cascade

Tags: bash, source

I have a number of scripts that are sourced in cascade.  Am new to this and would not mind having some examples, with some details of pros and cons?

Comment: It is unclear what the issues are that you are experiencing.

Comment: I want a good system that does not get difficult to manage as I build more functionality.  It is more about design than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before, so based upon my experience I would like to point out:

Sourcing scripts in cascade brings the obvious **advantage**:

- Sort of like ***units*** in Delphi or other big IDEs.

Sourcing scripts in cascade brings the less obvious **disadvantage**:

- Manageability. It is hard to manage (de-)duplication of code for example. Then there is the Shellcheck problem, which can still be solved by setting it to follow sources. Overall, the design thing, meaning to have multiple shell files sourced together is a good idea in theory, but in practice, it lead me to believe such an attempt is hard to manage.

---

I was trying to achieve my scripting goals using what you describe, but in the end, it was an utter failure. In my case, at least!

Comment: Right. Right.  It leads to some tough manageability difficulties as things progress.  How do you approach console functionality based on your experience.  Are there some codes I can introspect if you would share them. I like radical thought to tackle defeating attempts at things.